# How to calculate taxes owed on conversion from Traditional to Roth IRA in 2010?

Tags: united-states, taxes, roth-ira, ira

How do I calculate the taxes owed on a conversion from a Traditional IRA to a Roth IRA in 2010?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a calculator at [Kiplinger's website](http://www.kiplinger.com/tools/cost_of_conversion/) that takes into account the 2010 deal to defer part of the tax into 2011 and 2012

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you look at the tax table at [Fairmark](http://fairmark.com/reference/2010reference.htm), it will show you your marginal rate, and you can see the impact of the conversion. Remember, you can split the amount and pay half on your 2010 return, half on 11's.